# PHP mysql search two tables for one value then combine it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

i have a question to manage display when search two tables for one and display it with relation table display. i give a sample

```
table "plates"

ID | NAME
----------------
1  | piza
2  | soft drink
3  | ice cream

table "ingredients"

ID | NAME 
-------------------
1  | tomato 
2  | pepperoni
3  | ice 
4  | mint leaf 
5  | lemon 
6  | ice manggo
7  | ice watermelon 

table "plate_ingredient_relations"

ID | PLATE_ID | PLATE_INGREDIENTS 
-----------------------------------
1  |     1    |     1
2  |     1    |     2
3  |     2    |     3
4  |     2    |     4
5  |     2    |     5
6  |     3    |     6
7  |     3    |     7
```

here my query if i want to search "ice"

```
SELECT 'plate' AS type, id, name FROM `plates` WHERE name like '%ice%'
UNION
SELECT 'ingredient', id, name FROM `ingredients` WHERE name like '%ice%'
```

and the result is this

```
type        | id | name 
---------------------------------
plate       |  3 | ice cream
ingredient  |  3 | ice
ingredient  |  6 | ice manggo
ingredient  |  7 | ice watermelon
```

and the question is. from that result. could i display the result like this ?

```
soft drink - ice 
ice cream  - ice manggo 
ice cream  - ice watermelon
```

if it related on table "plate_ingredient_relations"

Comment: Do a JOIN instead of a UNION.

Comment: you mean. join that 3 tabels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.name, " - ", i.name) as plate_ingredient
FROM

plate_ingredient_relations r
    JOIN plates p
        ON r.plate_id = p.id

    JOIN ingredients i
        ON r.plate_ingredients = i.id

WHERE
    p.name like '%ice%'
    OR i.name like '%ice%';
```

Answer (score 0):

#### JOIN TABLES

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT plates.NAME, ingredients.NAME FROM plate_ingredient_relations 
INNER JOIN plates on plate_ingredient_relations.plate_id = plates.id 
INNER JOIN ingredients ON plate_ingredient_relations.plate_ingredients = ingredients.id 
WHERE ingredients.name LIKE '%ice%'
```

Take a look to the INNER JOINS, and the compare sentences "ON" to match tables.

Let me know if works.